# Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix style but no taglibrary exists for that namespace

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, xml-namespaces, icefaces-3

I'm upgrading a web application from icefaces 1.8 to Icefaces 3.x and from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2. Whenever I open existing popups, I receive:

> "Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix style
>   but no taglibrary exists for that namespace."

of course, this is shown trough:

```
<ice:messages
    globalOnly="true"
    styleClass="graRequired" />
```

These are the namespaces I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:gra="http://www.gravitant.com/components">
```

I spent a few hours on this and I wasn't able to find out what can cause this issue.

Is there anybody who met something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix style but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.*

This may happen when you're using plain HTML `<style>` element while not having the default XML namespace declared as `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`. But this is unlikely as you already have declared it in the `<ui:composition>` snippet in your question.

Another probable cause is you're using the literal string `style:` in a XML element or attribute, which indicates a XML namespace prefix (like as `h:` is the XML namespace prefix of standard JSF component set and `ice:` is that for ICEfaces component set).

Given that you didn't awarely declare such a XML namespace, and the "style" being recognizable as a standard HTML element attribute, this in turn strongly suggests that you accidently used the following somewhere in the XHTML file:

```
<someElement style:"bar">
```

instead of

```
<someElement style="bar">
```

Just do a Ctrl+F on `style:` and fix accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, your explanation indeed seems to be pertinent but I am unable to find such a case ("style:") in any of my jsp/jsf/xhtml files...

Comment: Well, then it's time to create an SSCCE. Copypaste a minimum of the offending code into a completely blank sandbox project and then strip down as many as possible lines of code as long as the problem is still reproducible. You should end up with only a couple of lines which still reproduces the problem in another completely blank sandbox project by just copypasting, and then post it here (so that we can reproduce it ourselves!). My best guess would be that something in `xmlns:gra="http://www.gravitant.com/components` is causing the trouble. Perhaps a broken taghandler?

Comment: I found the cause... I had `<style type="text/css">...` inside a `ui:composition`! Thanks!

Comment: That should work just fine. Or did that `<ui:composition>` not have a `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, on the contrary to what you have shown in the question?

Comment: Exactly... It was missing that... In my example I posted my current popup page, but this was also included and hard to discover. Thanks again.